# Measure based on multiple parameters

Tags: powerbi

How to create a measure based on multiple paramaters? I have table with given quantities per customer, by parameters I want to input prices per each customer and by measure I want calculate sales per each customer. But I don't know how to calculate it be each customer sepatately?
So in that example it shoud be Sales for Nikola= Nicola quantities x Nicola price parameter; Sales for Olaf=Olaf quantities x Olaf price parameter ect.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a sample data. That will help

Comment: @JonWay, source data are this way:
Customer Quantity
Nikola      100
Olaf          150 
ect
So what I want to do is to multiply quantity x value from parameter (which is price) for each customer. So there gonna be parameter for price for every customer.

Answer (score 0):

If for each customer the price varies maybe you should do another table with prices that contains the ID of the customer and the price.
Then you can make a relationship between the quantity table (lets say Sales) and the price table(Price).
Next step is to calculate quantity * price.
So you write:

Total Sales = SUMX('Sales', 'Sales'[Quantity], RELATED('Price'[Price])

If you create a table visual with the customer names and the Total Sales measure, you'll be able to see the total sales for each customer.
I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't want to create price table because I want to set a price  and be able to change it quickly so that's why I created parameter.